# How can I get video bitrate with javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get the bitrate of video that uploader, because the backend need it.

```
var video = document.createElement('video');
video.preload = 'metadata';
video.src = URL.createObjectURL(document.getElementById('fileUp').files[0]);
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(video.src);
console.log(video.bitrate);
```

Comment: @bZezzz No, this question does not mention dash.js.

Comment: I'm guessing this code doesn't work?  Also, wouldn't you want to call `revokeObjectURL()` _after_ getting the `video.bitrate`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I find out what quality the video has and how to change it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50982948/how-can-i-find-out-what-quality-the-video-has-and-how-to-change-it)

Comment: @flakerimi No, this question does not mention dash.js.

Comment: maybe let backend do this job better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the video duration then simply divide the file size by it to get an approximation (subtitles, audio and metadata would also be included in this value), as far as i know there is no standard api for getting the bitrate directly.

Example (credits https://stackoverflow.com/a/67899188/6072029 ) :

```
<div>
    <script>
        const getVideoInfos = (file) =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = () => {
                    const media = new Audio(reader.result);
                    media.onloadedmetadata = () => resolve({
                        duration: media.duration,
                        file_size: file.size,
                        bitrate: 8*file.size / media.duration,
                    });
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
            });

        const handleChange = async (e) => {
            const infos = await getVideoInfos(e.target.files[0]);
            document.querySelector("#infos").innerText = `Infos : ${JSON.stringify(infos, null, 4)}`;
        };


    </script>
    <input type="file" onchange="handleChange(event)" />
    <p id="infos">infos: </p>
</div>
```

Comment: bitrate calculation seems wrong. You need to multiply by 8 to get bits.